# Como remover colunas de um data frame?

Tags: r

Eu tenho esse data frame com 275 variáveis e gostaria de remover as variáveis que não estão contribuindo significativamente (que tenham valor diferente de 0 menos de 10 vezes).
Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Veja se ajuda: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605206/drop-data-frame-columns-by-name

Comment: Ajudou!! Muito obrigada!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma possível forma de fazer isso é usando a função `select_if` do pacote `dplyr`.

Primeiro defina uma função que conta o número de zeros:

```
contar_zeros <- function(x){
  sum(x == 0)
}
```

Agora considere este data.frame

```
df <- data_frame(
  x = 0,
  y = 1:10,
  z = c(rep(0,5), 6:10)
)
df
# A tibble: 10 × 3
       x     y     z
   <dbl> <int> <dbl>
1      0     1     0
2      0     2     0
3      0     3     0
4      0     4     0
5      0     5     0
6      0     6     6
7      0     7     7
8      0     8     8
9      0     9     9
10     0    10    10
```

Usando o `select_if`:

```
df_sem_colunas <- select_if(df, function(col) contar_zeros(col) < 10)
df_sem_colunas
# A tibble: 10 × 2
       y     z
   <int> <dbl>
1      1     0
2      2     0
3      3     0
4      4     0
5      5     0
6      6     6
7      7     7
8      8     8
9      9     9
10    10    10
```